# What is Laravel's $request->session()->regenerateToken() method used for?

Tags: laravel

I'm checking my Laravel's logout form and noticed this line of code in Laravel documentation website:

"In addition to calling the logout method, it is recommended that you invalidate the user's session and regenerate their CSRF token. "

And then use this method $request->session()->regenerateToken();

Since it does not say anything else about this CSRF token regeneration, I was wondering why would I need to regenerate CSRF token if I am trying to log the user out?

Answer (score 0):

### Session Fixation

**Description**

Session Fixation is an attack that permits an attacker to hijack a valid user session. The attack explores a limitation in the way the web application manages the session ID, more specifically the vulnerable web application. When authenticating a user, it doesn’t assign a new session ID, making it possible to use an existent session ID.

reference : [owasp.org](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Session_fixation)

---

There is the same link in the [**Laravel document**](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/session#regenerating-the-session-id).